# How to update data using Snowflake cursor?

Tags: python

I would like to get data from one column from  Snowflake table and then update other table column using Snowflake cursor code.
Please help.
Thanks :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.